# Autocomplete for kibana types in kibana-plugins

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, kibana-6

I'm developing plugin for kibana and I'm feeling pain due to absent IntelliSense.

Does anyone know how to add to IntelliSense support of kibana types in vscode when I open my kibana plugin folder?

Or maybe anyone know how to configure IntelliSense to enable autocompletion of types from sibling folder for JS project?

My folder structure is:

```
/kibana
/kibana-extra/myplugin
```

I'm opening directly `myplugin` folder. I tried to add following **jsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "include": [
        "../../kibana/src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../../kibana/src/**/__fixtures__/**/*"
    ]
}
```

But I have no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your plugin `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` (related on language used in your project) with the following content:

```
{
    // extend Kibana's tsconfig, or use your own settings
    "extends": "../../kibana/tsconfig.json",
    // tell the TypeScript compiler where to find your source files
    "include": [
        "server/**/*",
        "public/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Kibana's root folder already contains `tsconfig.json`, so you should extends it.

Found in [github kibana repo](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/docs/development/plugin/development-plugin-resources.asciidoc#typescript-support) and in [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)